# Please explain the significance of []() in C++

Tags: c++

I am building some HTML forms handlers using ESP32 in Arduino.

In a lot of tutorials I see something like the following...

```
update_server.on("/", HTTP_GET, []() {
    blah;
    blah;
 });
```

And here is another..

```
update_server.on("/update", HTTP_POST, []() {
    blah;
    blah;
}, []() {
    more blah;
    etc... 
});
```

Can someone please explain to me the [] and the () parts?

I have some vague feeling about these representing function calls, but I am having trouble finding references to this particular syntax.

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: They are [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) -- in other words, an adhoc function.  Read the documentation to see how the capture and parameter lists work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are lambda functions. They are functions without a name basically.

You can read more about it here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lambda-expression-in-cplusplus

Comment: Thanks for this, I was able to learn about Lambda from this. Mark.